# Validation and Test with TensorFlow

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I have created a one hidden layer neural network with a pyramidal architecture using TensorFlow. Here is the code:

```
num_classes = 10
image_size = 28

#Read the data
train_dataset, train_labels, valid_dataset, valid_labels, test_dataset, test_labels = OpenDataSets("...")
#Create and convert what is needed.
tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size * image_size))
tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

#Then I create the NN.
Wh = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([image_size * image_size, image_size * image_size / 2]))
bh = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([image_size * image_size / 2]))
hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, Wh) + bh)

Wout = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([image_size * image_size / 2, num_labels]))
bout = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_labels]))
logits = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden, Wout) + bout)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, tf_train_labels))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)
train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

And now I train my NN:

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    for step in range(1000):
        offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
        batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}
        _, l, predictions = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Now I would like to validate and test my NN after training. But I don't know how to create the new feed_dict and use session.run in order to validate/test.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will first have to create appropriate validation/test tensor functions. For one-layer MPL, it involves nested multiply with weights and addition of biases (and also Relu's since you have them in your original model). Define these right below your train predictions

```
valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(
                      tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(
                         tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, Wh) + bh)), Wout) + bout)))
test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(
                      tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(
                         tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, Wh) + bh)), Wout) + bout)))
```

These expressions are in fact quite identical to `logit` variable defined in your code, only using `tf_valid_dataset` and `tf_test_dataset` respectively. You can create intermediate variables to simplify them.

You will then have to create some validation/test function to test accuracy. Simplest would be to test most likely predicted class (Misclassification error roughly). Define this outside your graph/session.

```
def accuracy(predictions, labels):
      pred_class = np.argmax(predictions, 1)
      true_class = np.argmax(labels, 1)
      return (100.0 * np.sum(pred_class == true_class) / predictions.shape[0])
```

After that, you can simply pass this accuracy function inside same session/feed_dict to compute validation/test score.

```
print 'Validation accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels)
print 'Test accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So, if I understand it correctly I have to create two other NNs, which are in fact pointers onto my original NN, because they use exactly the same trainable weights. Am I right?

Comment: I expected to use my original NN with different inputs.

Comment: No no, you will use exact same network to validate - simply define two functions in same network and call accuracy() in same session